# How to override render() method from base view and add more options to template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Apologies, I'm a noob in terms of Backbone & Handlebars, and you'll see that my question is phrased in terms of a language I know a lot better, i.e. Java.

I'm looking for something which I'm sure must be a regularly used pattern.

I have a single page app where three views (let's call them RealView1, RealView2 and RealView3) extend from the same base view. None of these three have an explicit render() method; instead, the base view has its own render() like so:

```
    render: function () {
        console.log("I am BaseView");
        this.$el.html(this.template({readOnly: this.readOnly}));
        ...
        return this;
    }
```

As can be seen from the above, BaseView has a 'readOnly' boolean which is passed in via options when BaseView is constructed, i.e. via BaseView's initialize: function (options). readOnly can then be referred to in any related Handlebars templates.

What I now want to do is to extend the functionality of RealView3 (but ONLY that view) to have a new option passed into it called 'canEditRule'; this needs making available to the Handlebars template for RealView3, just the same as for 'readOnly' in it's BaseView 'parent'.

My question is this: I presume that I need to somehow provide RealView3 with it's own render() method that:

(a) Implements/overrides render() from BaseView, and,

(b) Makes the canEditRule option available to the RealView3 Handlebars template in addition to the readOnly option that already exists in BaseView

I'm no wiser having read the Backbone & Handlebars documentation - maybe I'm not looking for the right thing in the right place! Could someone kindly provide me with a code snippet that does what I'm looking for ?

Comment: please Read more About ```HOC (Higher Order Component)```

Comment: @hamed hossani  HOC appears to be a ReactJS concept ? I'm not using ReactJS, I'm using Backbone.

Comment: `canEditRule` sounds a lot like `readOnly = false`. Can't you just pass this as false while creating `RealView3`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply extend `BaseView` and override the `render` method:

```
const RealView3 = BaseView.extend({
  // ...
  render() {
      this.$el.html(
          this.template({
              readOnly: this.readOnly,
              canEditRule: this.canEditRule,
          })
      );
  }
});
```